# Appending Play classpath with relative path

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I need my shell script in "bin" to include `"$lib_dir/../conf"` in the `app_classpath`, because there is a required persistence.xml in that directory.

How do I tell Play to include this relative path in app_classpath for the generated shell script?

I'm new to Play framework.  It seems to be geared towards collecting all the needed jars from various locations, and putting them neatly under `$lib_dir`.  The problem is I need it to also include an XML in a fixed, relative location.